# IF function in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

Is it possible to have substring/left and if function in crystal report?
I mean like I want to get the first 2 characters of my name_column 
then if the substring of the name_column is 'XO' then I would like the new field in formula to be 1000 or if it is 'XD' then it is 2000..
Any help would be appreciated.. Thank you so much before

NB: I use vb.net and sqlserver

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I agree with @Ryan, the answer is in your question.  So, are you having trouble making it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// {@Foobar}
SELECT Left({TABLE.name_column},2)
CASE "XO": 1000
CASE "XD": 2000
DEFAULT : -1
```